# How to transfer a large file ( ~1MB) through ble?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am building an application that lets user change the watch faces of Amazfit GTS / GTS 2 / Mi Band 4 / Mi Band 5 (basically a fitness watch). I am using the plugin [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) to connect my device with watch. I need to transfer .bin files (~1MB) to the watch to change watch face. The .bin files can be found [here](https://amazfitwatchfaces.com/mi-band-5/fresh). I am able to connect my android device with the watch. I can also list all the services, characteristics and descriptors.

I read online that large data is sent in chunks over ble.

Now there are so many characteristics and I don't understand in which characteristic data is to be written, how to be written? And how do I know that chunk of data has successfully reached the watch?

If needed I can share all the services, characteristics screenshots.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sending more data than what can fit in an attribute value can be done in many different ways and hence depends on target device. See the documentation for your target device how they have set up the expected flow.

Comment: How are the bin files usually put on the watch?

Comment: This application can put bin files on watch https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mc.miband1 . I don't know how they do it.

Comment: This open source Android application seems to do something similar to what you want https://codeberg.org/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge/

Comment: Did you find an answer? Did you replace the OS on the device with and android os?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution.

First, try requesting higher MTU in your BLE device after the successful connection. This will speed up transfer speed. It automatically chooses the highest MTU possible (Bluetooth 5.x is 512 bytes).

```dart
if (Platform.isAndroid) await device!.requestMtu(512);
```

Then send the utf8 encoded iteratively into blocks/chunks.

```dart
void send(Uint8List fileContents) async {
  if (fileContents.isEmpty) return;

  int bytesAlreadySent = 0;
  int bytesRemaining = fileContents.length - bytesAlreadySent;
  
  // Try not making this value closer to your MTU,
  // it will affect the reliability of the connection
  int maxBlockLength = 128;

  while (bytesRemaining > 0 && isFileTransferInProgress) {
    int blockLength = min(bytesRemaining, maxBlockLength);
    Uint8List blockView = Uint8List.view(fileContents.buffer, bytesAlreadySent, blockLength);

    await fileBlockCharacteristic?.write(blockView).then((_) {
      bytesRemaining -= blockLength;
      print("File block written - $bytesRemaining bytes remaining");
      bytesAlreadySent += blockLength;
    }).catchError((e) {
      print("File block write error with $bytesRemaining bytes remaining");
      isFileTransferInProgress = false;
    });
  }
}
```